# iOS UI elements are invisible

Tags: ios, uikit

I work on a project for few days. All worked great until today. I've added few elements to view just like normal today. But when I launch app on device I can't see them. They are there: size classes works ok, everything is on right place. I can even touch UISegmentedControl and pick item on UIPickerView that makes the Picker View noise. But they are invisible - I can see only older elements.

I can't even tell where is the problem, because new elemts have THE SAME setting as olders. Methods like [_someElement setHidden:NO] does nothing.

Can you help me please?

Edit: they are visible in IB Preview

Comment: Please post some code and/or your storyboard.

Comment: Is it possible you've placed them behind a view that hides them? I would have check first the views hierarchy in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

probably bug with cache, try to:

-delete all data from DerivedData folder
/Users/%user name%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

-manually remove application from device/simulator

rebuild application

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved it after few hours, when I was focusing on another problem.

AVFoundatuon preview layer hide those elements. Simple solution is to bring them to the top as subviews.

Thank you.

Comment: Known issue when using AV... layers. (Had it with AVPlayer). Thought that hiding view/layer might be the issue.